# Turn Linq Aggregate with seed around

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for the equivalent of `Aggregate`—the overload that takes a seed—but which extends from the seed instead of from the aggregating collection. That is, given a collection of `Func<T, bool>` (suitable for use in a `Where`) I'd like to apply them in succession to a base collection. So given this setup:

```
class Product {
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

var products = new List<Product> {
    new Product { Name = "toaster", Size = 100, Price = 49 },
    new Product { Name = "pencil", Size = 2, Price = 5 },
    new Product { Name = "Oven", Size = 500, Price = 1000 }
}.AsEnumerable();

var conditions = new List<Func<Product, bool>> {
    { o => o.Size > 50 },
    { o => o.Price < 100 }
}.AsEnumerable();
```

Instead of:

```
return conditions.Aggregate(enumerable, (current, condition) => current.Where(condition));
```

I'd like to instead be able to use:

```
return enumerable.WhereAll(conditions);
```

Is this something that I just have to write my own extension method for, or is there a way to achieve this with native Linq extension methods? I think that the `Aggregate` syntax can be confusing in the case where there is no real aggregation occurring (at least, how a developer would think about it). If I did use `Aggregate`, I think it would be surprising or confusing in the code, first because there's no real aggregation occurring (such as summing or concatenating) and second because when `conditions` is an empty collection, it still returns the seed (a somewhat non-idiomatic and surprising result for working with collections and extension methods, where the return value is not a transformation of the object upon which the extension method operates).

I'm open to better names than `WhereAll`. I've considered `Transform`, `Map`, and `Apply`.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, I clicked on the wrong tag suggestion!

Comment: What about `WhereAll`?

Comment: nothing exists like that afaik so you should have to write your own.

Comment: @Daniel <smacks forehead> Yes, of course. I said the wrong thing. I meant `Where` all along. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `products.Where(p => conditions.All(c => c(p)))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns all products `p` where all conditions `c` return true when passed `p`:

```
products.Where(p => conditions.All(c => c(p)));
```

Comment: Looks like @dasblinkenlight and I got the same solution--if they post an answer I'll delete this one.

Comment: This is great and I learned something. But I have to be more careful with my questions because this is actually for an `IQueryable`. So great answer, wrong question. Sigh.