# Turn Linq to Entities Aggregate with seed around

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

With Entity Framework 6, I'm looking for the equivalent of `Aggregate`—the overload that takes a seed—but which extends from the seed instead of from the aggregating collection. That is, given a collection of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` (suitable for use in a `Where`) I'd like to apply them in succession to a base `IQueryable`.

Note: Even though `Aggregate` is itself unsupported in Linq to Entities, the trick is that we're not trying to project the `Aggregate` operation into SQL, we're using the `IEnumerable` method `Aggregate` to add where conditions to an `IQueryable`. So `Aggregate` works with EF as long as `IQueryable` is the seed, not the `this` parameter of the extension method.

So given this setup:

```
public class Product {
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

var products = new List<Product> {
    new Product { Name = "toaster", Size = 100, Price = 49 },
    new Product { Name = "pencil", Size = 2, Price = 5 },
    new Product { Name = "Oven", Size = 500, Price = 1000 }
}.AsEnumerable(); // please pretend this is an `IQueryable`

var conditions = new List<Func<Product, bool>> {
    { o => o.Size > 50 },
    { o => o.Price < 100 }
}.AsEnumerable(); // please pretend this is of Expression<Func<Product, bool>>
```

Instead of:

```
IQueryable<Product> filtered =
   conditions.Aggregate(queryable, (current, condition) => current.Where(condition));
```

I'd like to instead be able to use:

```
IQueryable<Product> filtered = queryable.WhereAll(conditions);
```

Is this something that I just have to write my own extension method for, or is there a way to achieve this with native Linq to Entities extension methods? I think that the `Aggregate` syntax can be confusing in the case where there is no real aggregation occurring (at least, how a developer would think about it). If I did use `Aggregate`, I think it would be surprising or confusing in the code, first because there's no real aggregation occurring (such as summing or concatenating) and second because when `conditions` is an empty collection, it still returns the seed (a somewhat non-idiomatic and surprising result for working with queryables/collections and extension methods, where the return value is not a transformation of the object upon which the extension method operates).

I'm open to better names than `WhereAll`. I've considered `Transform`, `Map`, and `Apply`.

If this were just for `IEnumerables` and Linq to Objects, [the answer is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33679725/57611):

```
products.Where(p => conditions.All(c => c(p)));
```

However, this can't be projected into SQL for Linq to Entities because you can't manually work with an expression inside a lambda to have the expression properly added to the parent expression tree (the expression itself has to be the whole lambda), unless you want to do complicated surgery on expressions with an `ExpressionVisitor` (overkill for this).

Comment: I voted to close this as unclear as you don't seem to be asking a question, unless it is "what do I name this". I think you are familiar enough with the language and EF that you can both write this as an extension and examine the exposed methods from a DbSet<> (there is no whereall). If you can focus this into an answerable question I will remove the close vote, but at the moment it doesn't seem there is a solution because there is no highlighted problem.

Comment: @TravisJ It was clear enough to some people! Thanks for your input.

Comment: You mean the creation of the extension method answer? Is that what you were looking for though? An edit would really help make this clearer. Are you asking for alternatives? It would really make your queries cleaner if you were to simply combine the expression trees before using them, that way there is no need for building these large queries.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple to write an extension method..

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> q,IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> conditions)
{
  foreach(var condition in conditions)
    q=q.Where(condition);
  return q;
}
```

You could also use a PredicateBuilder.  Initialize to True, and `AND` in all the conditions, then just use the regular `.Where` with the compound predicate you've built.

Comment: `WhereAll<T>` I believe. If you hadn't answered this, I would have posted something close, too, because I do know how to write the extension method. I just wondered if there was anything I'm missing because I'm not extremely familiar with EF.

Comment: Yes, `WhereAll<T>`, updated.  It's more about LINQ than EF.  But I don't know of any built in LINQ method that would do what you want exactly.  Most are just hacky ways (Aggregate) of doing the above.

Comment: Not every Linq expression can be used in EF because many Linq expressions can't be projected into SQL by EF (such as `Expression.Invoke`, though apparently Linq to Sql can project this). It's not outside the realm of possibility that some extension methods exist I'm not aware of or that do things I didn't know. I think it's worth asking because who knows what trick someone else might know that I don't?

Comment: Yes, here is a list of the supported methods for EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx and as I mentioned before, you can use a PredicateBuilder to transform your array of conditions into one single expression tree that you can use in a Where clause as well.